# how to use alt-tab when a menu is open

Tags: application-switcher

While the context menu or file-menu is open, any attempt to hit alt-tab (application-switcher) is ignored and the menu stays open. This happens in most applications (except for some chromium based apps like vs-code).

Question: How to force alt-tab even if a context menu is open?

Answer (score 1):

It is how it works. Finish your menu choice or close the menu before moving on to the next application.

Changing this behavior would likely require going deep into the source code and recompiling.

Answer (score 1):

Hit esc to close the opened menu and then alt+tab to switch application